# How can I send secure API requests from SvelteKit app, without showing API keys on the client side?

Tags: javascript, api, svelte, sveltekit, supabase

I'm using Supabase for a new Sveltekit app, with [this template](https://github.com/joshnuss/svelte-supabase)

Currently, I'm passing the Supabase keys through on the client side, like this:

```
const supabase = createClient(
  import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL,
  import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
)
```

What is the simplest way that I can create a secure backend/API, so the application can fetch content from Supabase, without showing Supabase key on the client side?

Is there any functionality built into Sveltekit that enables me to do this?  Or would I need to integrate a backend like Rails?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

SvelteKit supports server-side code in two main places:

- [endpoints](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-endpoints)
- [hooks](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#hooks)

Code for these will never be accessible to the browser; only the results. Also any network calls made will not be visible to the client since they all happen on the server (for cases where API keys are embedded in the URL). The `locals` property of each API is a good place to share sensitive data (like API keys) with all the server-side parts.

The general recommendation is to proxy external API calls with local endpoints:

1. Fetch a local SvelteKit endpoint from [SvelteKit pages](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-pages) (instead of calling the external API, like Supabase, directly). You can fetch the endpoint from two different places on a page:

   - [`load()`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#loading) in `<script context="module">` (allows calling API's from server-side before page is sent/rendered)
   - main `<script>`
2. Initialize the external API in a singleton.
3. Call the external API from the endpoint and return the results to the page.

Notes:

- SvelteKit endpoints are a generalization of serverless lambda functions. (See [Netlify](https://docs.netlify.com/functions/build-with-javascript/) or [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html) flavors)
- Any NPM modules used in endpoints/hooks must be devDependencies.
- `fetch()` is recommended (vs axios, for example), especially within `load()`. `load()` provides a special version of `fetch()` that caches calls from the server-side so the client-side can reuse the results.
- Step #2 is mainly to support serverless environments like Netlify.